# Redirect homepage url with slash to non-slash in NGINX

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I had to make redirects for urls with slash to non-slash urls.
I did it with the rule:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

But as I see this rule does NOT include the redirect for homepage:

```
https://example.com/ -> https://example.com
```

How can I also handle the redirect for homepage?

Comment: Why do you want to redirect that? `https://example.com/` and `https://example.com` will always send the `request_uri` as `/`

Comment: @TarunLalwani it's seo business requirement

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes this cannot be done. When you request `http://example.com` or `http://example.com/` then browser will always sent request to `http://example.com/`. The server will always see that a `/` was appended and you can't redirect to a blank URI and remove that `/`

[image: Request without slash]

As you can see in above image I didn't add `/` on the request url but `/` was still sent. Read the below question as well

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser/35646